# Aligning a collection of Div in same CSS Column

Tags: css

I am making a **3 column** grid using CSS Columns:

Here is the Grid structure:

```
______________ ________________ _________________
   div 1a           div 1b            div 1c  

   div 2a           div 2b            div 2c  

   div 3a           div 3b            div 3c
```

I am using following CSS code on parent div:

```
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
```

This works fine with three columns as above, **but** as soon as no. of items in column become 2 or 1, it becomes as:

```
______________ ________________ _________________
div 1a              div 3a            div 2b  
div 2a              div 1b            div 3b
```

That is it re-balances the two items into 3 columns.

How can i prevent this and put two items in two columns and one item in only 1 column ?

Comment: could you post your HTML/CSS, adding a fiddle would also be a good idea

Comment: It seems as though you're misunderstanding how the multi-column module works (keep in mind, it is not intended to be used for "grids").  What you're describing is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Columns weren't meant to be used as a foundation for building a grid system, which is essentially what you're looking for. Instead, you can really achieve this by simply floating and nesting divs wrapped in a container. That way when the number of 'rows' in the columns fluctuates, they will remain contained within their containers and not jump around from one column to the next. Something like this would probably suit what you're looking to do: Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u8sn/1/).

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Column One</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1c</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Column Two</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1b</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Column Three</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Column One</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1c</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Column Two</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>div1c</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body,
  html {
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  }
  .container {
      width: 100%;
      postition: relative;
  }
  .container:before,
  .container:after {
      content: " ";
      /* 1 */
      display: table;
      /* 2 */
  }
  .container:after {
      clear: both;
  }
  /* IE 6/7 */
  .container {
      *zoom: 1;
  }
  .col {
      width: 33.3%;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid green;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .row {
      border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```